# MySql 5.7 Error ( this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by)

Tags: python, mysql, group-by

I have seen several answers that say fix your query but I have `GROUP BY CONCAT` in my query and am not sure how to fix it.

```
 cur.execute('''
    SELECT user_id, symbol FROM first_sweep    
    WHERE date_time BETWEEN %s AND %s AND action = 'buy'
    GROUP BY CONCAT(user_id, "-",symbol) 
    ''', (min_rng, max_rng,))    
    fs = cur.fetchall()
```

The full error I am getting is:

```
(1055, "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'stockpicker.first_sweep.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, MySql 5.7 and Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(user_id, '-', symbol) as usym, 
  MAX(user_id) AS user_id, 
  MAX(symbol) AS symbol
FROM first_sweep    
WHERE date_time BETWEEN %s AND %s AND action = 'buy'
GROUP BY usym
```

Comment: Thank you. Why the MAX lines though? Just curious.

Comment: The columns aren't in the GROUP BY clause, at least not as bare columns. All columns that aren't in the GROUP BY must be in aggregate functions in the select-list to satisfy MySQL's check. You and I know that there's bound to be exactly one value of `user_id` and `symbol` per group, so `MAX()` will choose from a set of one value. But MySQL apparently can't make this inference in this case.